# Add custom folder with Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created a program that reads some text files from a folder usually located in C:\CustomFolder\Subfolder . Now I have also created an installer using "Microsoft Visual Studio 1027 Installer Projects" , but I would like that it creates also the folder C:\CustomFolder\Subfolder with its txt files on the target machine when it installs the software.

I have only found how to add folders to other system folder, but not directly to C:\ .
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

In the File System view in the setup project, right click that File System node, then Add Special Folder, then Custom Folder. In the properties window of that custom folder in DefaultLocation put [WindowsVolume] (it's not in the drop-down list).

[WindowsVolume] will be the volume where Windows is installed, which is probably what you mean by "C drive". The value will be C:\ so you can then right-click that new custom folder and create a folder called CustomFolder, and than add another folder called Subfolder and so on.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372817(v=vs.85).aspx